# Is Sybase {ASE} uses "schema.table" or just "table"

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

ALL,

The title pretty much says it all. I was looking [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1570/html/tables/X14933.htm), but couldn't find any information about the schema.

Could someone please sched some light?

I know MS SQL Server uses "schema.name" to reference a table in a database, but for Sybase I'm not sure.

TIA!

---

EDIT:

I guess I should be more specific.

I know in MS SQL Server it is possible to modify the table owner, but you can still select it with "SELECT su.name FROM sysobjects so, sysusers su, sys.tables t, sys.schemas s WHERE so.uid = su.uid AND t.object_id = so.id AND t.schema_id = s.schema_id AND s.name = ? AND so.name = ?;"

Now with Sybase everywhere I look the query to retrieve the table owner does not reference schema name only the table name. Does this mean that the table owner is not changeable in Sybase? Or it is changeable, but then the schema will also be changed?

Can someone shed some light please?

Answer (score 1):

In Sybase/SAP ASE, all tables have an owner; this owner is effectively the same thing as a schema.

That link you mention points to the *sysobjects* (system) table, which exists in every database.  *sysobjects* contains some high-level metadata for all objects (eg, tables, procs, triggers, views, etc) in the database.

Two columns of interest in the *sysobjects* table

- *name* : name of the object (eg, name of a table, name of a proc)
- *uid* : database user id of the object's owner

All system tables have an entry in *sysobjects* with *uid = 1*, which refers to the database owner (ie, *user_name(1) = dbo*).

In most environments it's typical for the database owner (*dbo*) to also own most other objects in the database (ie, most *sysobjects* rows have *uid=1*).

If an object is owned by someone other than the dbo, the *sysobjects* row will have uid = user_id('non_dbo_owner_name'); for example, if bob's database user id (uid) is 47, then any objects owned by bob will have *sysobjects.uid = 47*.

---

When you reference a table without an owner/schema name (eg, `select * from tab1`), ASE will first look for an object owned by you (ie, do you own a table named 'tab1') and if it doesn't find such a table then it looks for a table owned by the dbo (ie, does 'dbo.tab1' exist?).

When you reference a table with an owner/schema name attached, ASE will only look for the existence of that table.

If you don't own a table named 'tab1' then the following are equivalent:

- select * from tab1
- select * from dbo.tab1

---

In response to the updated question:

Sybase/SAP ASE does not support changing the owner of an object.

As for finding the owner(s)/schema(s) of a table, you've got a couple options:

```
select u.name as 'owner_name', 
       o.name as 'table_name'
from   sysobjects o,
       sysusers u
where  o.uid  = u.uid
and    o.name = '<name_of_table>'
and    o.type = 'U'

-- or

select user_name(o.uid) as 'owner_name', 
       o.name as 'table_name'
from   sysobjects o
where  o.name = '<name_of_table>'
and    o.type = 'U'
```

Comment: question updated with the context. Now my question is: where can I get the schema the table is contained in?

Comment: so in Sybase/SAP ASE "schema_name" = "table_owner_name" and you cannot change this, correct?

Comment: in PostgreSQL, I can do `SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' OR table_type = 'VIEW';`. How do I write it for Sybase/SAP ASE? It looks like sysdatabases is not connecting to sysobjects. Or does it?

Comment: 1) not sure why you're going against sysdatabases and 2) have you tried running the queries I've provided (above)?

Comment: it looks like for Sybase/ SAP ASE the database_name = catalog_name. And sysdatabases have a database_name. So, what I'm looking for is to get catalog_name, schema_name and table_name for for my DB. Unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: well, if you're sitting in the database (eg, you ran `use <dbname>`), you can obtain the database name with `db_name()`

Comment: So catalog_name IS the same as database_name and I;m right here as well, right?

Comment: some googling appears to show that 'catalog name' == 'database name'

Answer (score 0):

It works the same like in MS SQL Server. You can use `schema.object`.
If you use `object` then the object is searched:

- first in our schema
- then in `dbo` schema

You can also use the `database.owner.object` notation or `database..object` notation when owner is `dbo` or event `server.database.owner.object` notation when you connect an external ASE server.

Comment: question updated with more info. Could you clarify? Moreover if Sybase IS "schemaName.tableName", where can I get the schema name?